# Reading selected values of a segmented control in AppleScript

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm working on an AppleScript/ObjC project in Xcode, and I have a segmented control in my user interface and referenced to my AppDelegate.applescript as an IBOutlet. It allows for multiple selections.

How do I write a function to get the values of whatever segments of that segmented control that the user has selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you're refering to retriving the values of a property e.g.. Text Field then you can use the following Steps to learn how:

1. Create a Property for the text field in the AppDelegate.applescript:

   property myTextField : missing value
2. Connect the Property to the Object in the IB Builder
3. Use the Following code to retrive the current text in the text field:

   set textFieldText to myTextField's stringValue() as text
4. Use the variable: `textFieldText` as the value

got this from: http://asobjcresources.weebly.com

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have an defined a script property for the outlet for the NSSegmentedControl already, and since you allow multiple selections, you will have to iterate over each segment of the control and send it the ASOC equivalent of the

```
- (BOOL)isSelectedForSegment:(NSInteger)segment
```

message to build up a list of the selected segments.

Then, if a segment is selected, you could send:

```
- (NSString *)labelForSegment:(NSInteger)segment
```

to get more information about each segment.